# First line from multiple gz files

Tags: bash, gunzip, zcat

I know that there are multiple ways to read the first line from a gz file, for example:

```
gzcat abc.gz | head -n 1
```

or

```
gunzip -c abc.gz | awk 'NR==1 {print; exit}'
```

However, I have a directory with many, many gz files, and I want to get the header for each file (*.gz) with the filename next to it, like:

`abc.gz: This is the first line of abc.txt
 def.gz: This is the first line of def.txt`

Is there a quick way to do this?

[EDIT:] Thanks for the help! The answers are close, but I just want the filename next to each first line output so I know which line goes with which file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "GNU" `find` use:

```
find . -name "*.gz" -exec sh -c "echo -n '{}: '; gzcat {}|head -1" \;
```

Comment: find . -name "*.gz" -exec bash -c "gzcat {}|head -1" \;

abc.gz:   firstcol|secondcol|thirdcol
def.gz:   something|else|is|here

Comment: Nice, but why did you use double-quotes? and what is the point of bash while sh has the functionality required for this and is way faster? and lastly why didn't you use bulk exec with which less shell instances wil be spawned?

Comment: double quotes to add space, as shown in OP's desired output.

Comment: But, single quotes are safer, and more handy in this case